# Failure/Error with Ruby on Rails Tutorial Chapter 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Can anyone who has done this exercises help me out?

It's my first time using this programming language and not much to this, but I need to finish well until chapter 10 that is a final evaluation.

```
1) User pages edit with valid information 
     Failure/Error: describe "page" do
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `describe' for    #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_5::Nested_5::Nested_1:0xc283f8c>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:87:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages edit with valid information 
     Failure/Error: describe "page" do
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `describe' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_5::Nested_5::Nested_1:0xb67b1cc>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:87:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User pages edit with valid information 
     Failure/Error: describe "page" do
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `describe' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_5::Nested_5::Nested_1:0xc224244>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:87:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) User pages edit with valid information 
     Failure/Error: describe "page" do
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `describe' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_5::Nested_5::Nested_1:0xc562690>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:87:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) User pages edit with valid information 
     Failure/Error: describe "page" do
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `describe' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_5::Nested_5::Nested_1:0xc0559a4>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:87:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) User pages index 
     Failure/Error: visit users_path
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb__615083638_97671840'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7) User pages index 
     Failure/Error: visit users_path
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb__615083638_97671840'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  8) User pages index should list each user
     Failure/Error: visit users_path
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb__615083638_97671840'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  9) Authentication authorization after signing in should render the desired protected page
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_title('Edit user')
       expected #has_title?("Edit user") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:84:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.25 seconds
72 examples, 9 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:114 # User pages edit with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:115 # User pages edit with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:112 # User pages edit with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:113 # User pages edit with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:111 # User pages edit with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:15 # User pages index 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16 # User pages index 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:18 # User pages index should list each user
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:83 # Authentication authorization after signing in should render the desired protected page
```

---

## Edit

Here is my code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "index" do
    before do
      sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "Bob", email: "bob@example.com")
      FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "Ben", email: "ben@example.com")
      visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_title('All users') }
    it { should have_content('All users') }

    it "should list each user" do
      User.all.each do |user|
        expect(page).to have_selector('li', text: user.name)
      end
    end
  end

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
      describe "after submission" do
        before { click_button submit }

        it { should have_title('Sign up') }
        it { should have_content('error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com') }

        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
        it { should have_title(user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
      end
    end
   end

    describe "edit" do
       let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      sign_in user
      visit edit_user_path(user)

    describe "page" do
      it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
      it { should have_title("Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content('error') }
    end
  end

   describe "with valid information" do
      let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
      let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
      before do
        fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
        fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
        fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
        fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Save changes"
      end

      it { should have_title(new_name) }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      specify { expect(user.reload.name).to  eq new_name }
      specify { expect(user.reload.email).to eq new_email }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: We can't help you fix your code if you don't supply any code and don't specify how you're running it.

Comment: I mark errors are of two classes user_pages_spec

Comment: You seem to have posted [example code from the tutorial](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb) but not given any details as to what you have done with it or how you are trying to run the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is formatted like this:

```
describe "edit" do
   let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before do
  sign_in user
  visit edit_user_path(user)

describe "page" do
  it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
  it { should have_title("Edit user") }
  it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
end
```

I can see that it is probably broken without reading any of your code.

Are all your code blocks properly closed? Does not look so!

Comment: yes, thank you and I resolved the problem, I had bad one described, I modify and run entirely

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the unclosed blocks that phoet pointed out, which are causing your "undefined method describe" errors, you're getting errors in `/app/views/users/index.html.erb` line 5. The error is `` undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass `` which means there's a variable on that line that you're doing `variable.each` with, but you're either not setting that variable or when you're setting it, it's getting set to `nil`.

In general, the way for you to successfully get through this is to read the error messages and try to fix what they're complaining about. If you search for each error message individually, you'll find stack overflow questions about the specific issue that will help you.